Getting NullPointerException when running o.a.c.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest

I was trying to run the JVM distributed (upgrade) tests under test/distributed/org/apache/cassandra/distributed/upgrade with the command:
ant test-jvm-dtest-some -Duse.jdk11=true -Dtest.name=org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest

and got null pointer exception as following:
[junit-timeout] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[junit-timeout] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest
[junit-timeout] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.153 sec
[junit-timeout] 
[junit-timeout] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
[junit-timeout] INFO  [main] <main> 2024-04-04 21:49:43,719 Versions.java:136 - Looking for dtest jars in /Users/allenwang/Documents/xlab/cross-system/cassandra/build
[junit-timeout] Found 4.0.13, 4.0.9
[junit-timeout] Found 4.1.4
[junit-timeout] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
[junit-timeout] Testcase: simpleUpgradeWithNetworkAndGossipTest(org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest):  Caused an ERROR
[junit-timeout] null
[junit-timeout] java.lang.NullPointerException
[junit-timeout]     at org.apache.cassandra.distributed.shared.Versions.getLatest(Versions.java:127)
[junit-timeout]     at org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTestBase$TestCase.lambda$upgrades$1(UpgradeTestBase.java:152)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
[junit-timeout]     at org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTestBase$TestCase.upgrades(UpgradeTestBase.java:149)
[junit-timeout]     at org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTestBase$TestCase.upgradesFrom(UpgradeTestBase.java:141)
[junit-timeout]     at org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest.simpleUpgradeWithNetworkAndGossipTest(UpgradeTest.java:37)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[junit-timeout]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[junit-timeout] 
[junit-timeout] 
[junit-timeout] Test org.apache.cassandra.distributed.upgrade.UpgradeTest FAILED


I'm running with Java-11 and in Cassandra-4.1.4.
I put the dtest-4.0.9.jar, dtest-4.0.13.jar, and dtest-4.1.4.jar under build/ directory.
I also tried different versions of Cassandra but all got the same NPE failure.
Also I didn't find Versions.java file in the Cassandra repo, which makes it even harder for myself to figure out the reason.
I appreciate any help!!! Thank you so much
